# Yii2 restrict access to files

Tags: file, security, download

I have Yii2 application where users can upload and share files of different types. Once a file is uploaded, it could be downloaded only by certain other users and there are a whole bunch of checks that go behind this process.

My problem is that the files are stored on the server and if someone has the link directly to the file then they can easily be downloaded without going through any kind of authorization or security checks. How can I prevent this?

P.S. It could be any kind of solution, not one related to Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach comes to my mind.

1. Store the files at a location in file system that is not made publicly accessible by a web server.
2. Make them available by reading them from file system and sending them to browser when the user retrieves the URL that also does the security checks. A redirect to another URL that does not do security checks has to be avoided.

If you give more details about a more specific problem or question people can give you more specific information.